# Is it possible to use Groovy with Spring Roo?

Tags: groovy, spring-roo, spock

Is there a way to use Groovy in a Spring Roo project? 
I'm using STS (Eclipse) and I'd like to be able to write some code in Groovy
and use Spock framework for unit testing.
But it seems, there are some problems with AspectJ and Groovy intergation.
Has anyone successfully used Roo and Groovy together?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you describe more precisely your error ? I've found this, check it out, it could help : http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/77555-aspectj-is-not-working-in-groovy and http://andrewclement.blogspot.fr/2010/01/groovy-and-aspectj-load-time-weaving.html
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot mix those two languages in the same project.

When you installed Groovy-Eclipse you install a patched eclipse java compiler that is then able to build java and groovy code. When you install AspectJ you get an alternative compiler that can build java and AspectJ source (your Roo projects are AspectJ projects).

In a Roo project it will be using the AspectJ compiler and not the patched java compiler installed via Groovy-Eclipse, so it won't understand groovy code.

The proper solution is to patch AspectJ in the same way Groovy-Eclipse is done so AspectJ can build groovy+java+aspectj but we still haven't gotten around to that.

The easiest thing for you to do is split the tests into a separate Groovy test project that depends on the Roo project containing the main sources. That should work.